# How to get() in IndexedDB the value by key?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I want to get the value of a entry definied by key from my indexedDB. The Code where i want to extract the value looks as follows:

```
request.onsuccess = function (event) {
      db = request.result;
      transaction = db.transaction("Off-DB", "readwrite");
      store = transaction.objectStore("Off-DB");

      db.onerror = function(event){
        console.log("ERROR" + event.target.errorCode);
      }

      store.put({value: data});

      var mystorage = store.get(1);

      transaction.complete = function() {
        db.close();
      }
    }
```

I think the Code is working so far because i get this out out debugging my program:

[image: Browser Screenshot]

The get()-Method is extracting something. But i want that in the variable mystorage should be just the value of the IndexedDB entry.

What i've done so far do solve the problem: 
- reading documentations about get()-method in indexedDB
- there is one post on stackoverflow that discusses this issue. but i could not solve the problem with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the question on my own:

```
          db.transaction("Off-DB").objectStore("Off-DB").get(4).onsuccess = function(event) {
        console.log("Your value is:" + event.target.result.value);
      };
```

With this code you get the value of key 4 of your indexedDB.